# How can I plot a line with a confidence interval in python using plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to use plotly to plot a graph similar to the one here below:

[image]

Unfortunately I am only able to plot something like this
[image]

What I would like is to have normal boundaries (upper and lower defined by two dataframe columns and only one entry in the legend.

```py
    import plotly.graph_objs as go
    
    # Create a trace for the lower bound
    trace1 = go.Scatter(x=df.index, 
                        y=df['lower'], 
                        name='Lower Bound',
                        fill='tonexty',
                        fillcolor='rgba(255,0,0,0.2)',
                        line=dict(color='blue'))
    
    # Create a trace for the median
    trace2 = go.Scatter(x=df.index, 
                        y=df['median'], 
                        name='median',
                        line=dict(color='blue', width=2))
    
    
    # Create a trace for the upper bound
    trace3 = go.Scatter(x=df.index, 
                        y=df['upper'], 
                        name='Upper Bound',
                        fill='tonexty',
                        fillcolor='rgba(255,0,0,0.2)',
                        line=dict(color='blue'))
    
    # Create the layout
    layout = go.Layout(xaxis=dict(title='Date'), 
                       yaxis=dict(title='title'))
    
    # Create the figure with the three traces and the layout
    fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1, trace2, trace3], layout=layout)


    context['pltyplot'] = pltyplot(fig, output_type="div")
```

I want to use plotly because I am integrating the resulting figure into a django web page and plotly enables, with the las line, to import the whole object in a clean, simple and interactive way into the poge.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2, 4, 5, 3, 6]

# Define the confidence interval
interval = 0.6 * np.std(y) / np.mean(y)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines', name='Line'))


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x+x[::-1], 
                        y=y+[i + interval for i in y[::-1]],
                        fill='toself',
                        fillcolor='rgba(0,100,80,0.2)',
                        line=dict(width=0),
                        showlegend=False))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x+x[::-1], 
                        y=y+[i - interval for i in y[::-1]],
                        fill='toself',
                        fillcolor='rgba(0,100,80,0.2)',
                        line=dict(width=0),
                        showlegend=False))

fig.show()
```

[image]